# Viewing a web page in Android

Tags: java, android, google-authentication

I'm trying to get this web page and extract the list of android apps in the background:

https://play.google.com/store/account?purchaseFilter=apps

The page requires a log-in in order to view it, so how do I do it? I can't find any tutorials on the web about this.

Answer (score 1):

You need to connect to the play store via its API, then connect the account of which you want to extract the apps. See examples in the [Google Play Developer API](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client).

Comment: How do you connect the account to the API? I have tried using that but I don't know how to extract the needed authentication tokens to properly view the web page.

Comment: I have used the account manager with no success: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44962732/android-google-authentication-invalid-scope